Unbounded expansion in Tex
I'm trying to write a macros for processing lists.
Here's a simplified version of what I'm using to do that.
\def\processlist#1{
\ifx#1\relax
   \let\next=\relax
\else\ifx#1, 
   \let\next=\relax
\else 
   #1%
   \let\next=\processlist
\fi\fi
\next
}

I also need to store the list inside a macro once it's been processed. Here's the wrapper I'm using for that
\edef\processedlist{\processlist a,b,c,d\relax}

I run into a problem though when I try to run my code. It doesn't compile and TeX complains I've put an extra "else" statement somewhere in it, which I have not.
Looking at the stack trace, I think the real problem is that edef is expanding \processlist in \let\next=\processlist instead of assigning it to \next.
To confirm my suspicions, I put a \noexpand infront of \processlist, as in \let\next=\noexpand\processlist, and let the expansion proceed one step at a time.
Here's a bit of what I saw
One expansion:
> \processedlist=macro:
b \let \next =\processlist \next ,c,e,a\relax 

Two:
> \processedlist=macro:
b \let \next =\let \next =\relax \next ,c,e,a\relax  

Like I said, it seems like TeX is expanding \processlist instead of assigning it to \next. However, this seems to be at odds with what the TeXbook says about edef, which is that it's supposed to follow the normal rules of expansion, meaning that expansion is supposed to suppressed while \let is gathering arguments.
I'm not sure what to do to fix my code. I was hoping someone might be able to give me a hand.

Assignments are not performed inside an \edef.

\ifx#1\relax tests if the first two tokens are equal I assume that is not intended but you do not really say what you intend this code to do.   laTeX already has extensive functions for processing comma lists, see the clist module in texdoc interface3 you may prefer to use those functions.

I think the real problem is that edef is expanding \processlist in \let\next=\processlist  . No it is expanding in the \edef (the \let does not execute inside an edef it just expands to the same tioken.

\edef\foo{...\let\next=... } expands to ...\let<expansino of \next>=... which is not what you want. \let in unexpandable, so the expansion during \edef only copies it to the output, but \next is typically a macro (with a previous value when \next was used in some other internal macro.
You have to create your macro expandable without any assignment (or prefix assignments by \immediateassignment as egreg said). The most simple expandable macro should look like this:
\def\processlist#1{%
   \ifx\relax#1\else
      \ifx,#1% insert nothing
      \else #1%
      \fi
      \expandafter\processlist
   \fi
}

\processlist a,b,c,d\relax

\edef\processedlist{\processlist a,b,c,d\relax}

{\tt\meaning\processedlist}

\bye


Thanks! Appreciate you taking the time to answer my question. Just a followup. I asked egreg this too, so who every wants to answer first can: what's the point of the \expandafter before \processlist?

\expandafter\first\two expands \two and runs \first<expanded \two>. In this example \expandafter\processlist\fi expands \fi (closes previously opened if branch and removes \fi from input queue) and then runs \processlist. The \fi token is not here in this time, so \processlist takes next token from the outer input queue.

TeX doesn't perform assignments in \edef, so \let\next is out of question.
Assuming plain TeX
\long\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\long\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}

\def\processlist#1{%
  \ifx#1\relax
    \expandafter\firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\secondoftwo
  \fi
  {}{\innerprocesslist#1}%
}
\def\innerprocesslist#1{%
  \ifx#1,%
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
  \processlist
}

\processlist a,b,c,d\relax

\edef\processedlist{\processlist a,b,c,d\relax}

{\tt\meaning\processedlist}

\bye


With LaTeX:
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\processlist}{m}
 {
  \clist_use:nn {#1} {}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\processlist{a,b,c,d}

\edef\processedlist{\processlist{a,b,c,d}}

\texttt{\meaning\processedlist}

\end{document}

The output is exactly the same.
With plain LuaTeX you can perform assignments in \edef, but you need some changes anyway.
\def\processlist#1{%
  \ifx#1\relax
    \immediateassignment\def\next{}%
  \else
    \ifx#1,%
      \immediateassignment\let\next=\processlist
    \else
      #1%
      \immediateassignment\let\next=\processlist
    \fi
  \fi
  \next
}


Thanks, I appreciate the quick response. A followup about the plain TeX solution so I can understand expansion better: is the \expandafter after \firstoftwo and \secondoftwo to prevent them from accidentally thinking the closing \fi is their first argument?

@Harry Yes, that's correct.

One more follow up. So TeX doesn't read a \if \else \fi block in its entirety and replace it with one of its branches? Instead, it picks a branch to expand and then continues expanding the macros in that branch, without necessarily removing the final \fi?

@Harry If the test returns false, the true text is skipped until \else or \fi that don't get removed. Only macro expansion removes them. If the test returns true, the false branch (if any) will be removed by the expansion of \else.
